# Remove .NET Framework project templates in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-4.8

can i remove .Net Framework?
I only use ASP.Net Core 5.0 In Visual Studio 2019(2022 .Net 8.0 Maybe in the future)

i want remove all of this :

[image]

and if possible remove F# too??

I don't want to have any problems with Develop and running ASP.Net Core.
(How about console or desktop application?)

Comment: Open the Visual Studio installer and remove the components you don't want.

Comment: I'm voting to close based on the confusion in this question (removing .Net Framework is really ambiguous - it actually sounds like asking about uninstalling it from the PC). Yes, the image clarifies the question - but images are not searchable. Maybe it can be improved with a better title and better question wording?

Comment: @Ralf yes bro i know it, but when i want remove .net framework => VS say: "it looks like you trying to remove a component that's required by following : asp.net and web development"

Comment: yes you need to remove old asp.net (non-core) as well, if it uses old .net framework

Comment: @topsail Look at the "title" it is clear...and whats your suggestion

Comment: honestly, I'd just leave it there; hard drive capacity is cheaper than your time doing this, and definitely cheaper than your time fixing it if it goes wrong

Comment: I thiunk it meant that it could be confused with removing .NET framework installed on your machine, whereas your question is just about removing the ability to Visual Studio to propose them in new project window.

Comment: @Pac0 So, according to you, I will have no problem in develop console,web application ,desktop application (.Net Core) ?

Comment: no, not desktop application (unsure what is exactly the status on cross-platofrm desktop development with .NET). But asp_net core does work only with .net core as dependency (and you can deploy it on a non-windows machine)

Comment: @MarcGravell I think it's a really good answer, thank you, but I'm tired of seeing 2 of everything (example : console .framework and console .Net core )

Comment: @Pac0 Oh, it's very important. Thanks, post so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the .NET framework development options from the Visual Studio installer directly.

This implies maybe removing some other options that depend on it, e.g. ASP.NET ("classic", non-core). ASP.NET Core is usable with only .NET Core / recent ".NET" non-Framework.

In any case you can activate the option again in case you made a mistake.